# Writing a query in knex, where i need to use where with the insert query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

This is the raw query, which is working -

```sql
Insert into members (activity, emp_id, plan_id) VALUES ('admin', 21937, 2463) on conflict(emp_id, plan_id) where ("responsibility" != 'admin')  DO Nothing;
```

Converted this query into knex query, but it's avoiding the where clause when I printed the query build by knex.

```js
let result = knex('members').withSchema('public').insert(insertParameters);
result = result
  .whereNotIn({
    'member.responsibility': 'admin',
  })
  .onConflict(['emp_id', 'plan_id'])
  .ignore();
result = await result.returning('id');
return result;
```

Query prepared by knex -

```sql
insert into "public"."member" ("plan_id", "responsibility", "emp_id") values ($1, $2, $3), ($4, $5, $6), ($7, $8, $9) on conflict ("emp_id", "plan_id") do nothing returning "id"
```

There is an index created for columns -`emp_id, plan_id, and responsibility != 'admin'`, so we need to write the where clause.

Comment: INSERT **cannot** have a where clause. You may be able to reformat the statement to an *insert into <table>(<list>) select <list> where parm !='admin'*. But I suggest the generated query is in fact correct.

Comment: Probably that case is not supported by knex 0.95.